# Email id in textview is clicked in ios

Tags: ios, uitextview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an `UITextView` contains large string in which it contains Email Id's.When an email id is clicked i have to open `MFMailComposeViewController` and the email id should be under lined in the `UITextView`

I Tried  as below

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAddress;        
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Comment: set textview.editable = NO;

Comment: @ Jageen  :Thanks for your reply,it is working. How can we underline that text?

Comment: @mashu sorry i don't know about it

Comment: @Madhu UItextview text is static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
textview.text = @"user@example.com";
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
textview.editable = NO;
```

It will detect it as email address and when you click it will open view to send email.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NSAttributedString help of NSRange like below

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Some String"];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName 
                   value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle] 
                   range:(NSRange){0,5}];
```

you can set desired color like below

```
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```